# Add attribute to tinymce formats

Tags: tinymce-4

I'm going to add `dir:left` to `code` tags.

```
<code dir="left">my inline code </code>
```

i know [from here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/format-custom/) how to add style to custom format but i need to add this **attribute** (not style) to all `code` tags

Answer (score 1):

ok.i found it. just needed to create a new plugin for tinymce:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('stylebuttons', function (editor, url) {
  ....
onClick: function () {
         ....
                tinymce.activeEditor.dom.setAttrib(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('code'), 'dir', 'left');

        },
}
```